# One Service Multiple Activities in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, service

I have a service and 3 activities. The service is started in the first activity.
Now when I move to the second activity and pressing on some button, I want
to send a data to the service.

so in the second activity, inside the click listener I did the following:

```
 Intent service = new Intent(MyService.class.getName()); 
 service.putExtra("dataToSend",data.toString());
 startService(service);
```

but the method **onStartCommand** inside the service, doesn't get called..

Also, I want to create this service to work with multiple activities.
I mean each activity will be able to send a data to this service and get a data
from it.

Comment: Show the service code

Comment: To get data I would recommend EventBus as it is by far the easiest method that I have found compared to binding to the activity or sending broadcasts (assuming that the service emits data). If you need on-demand access to data you will probably have to bind to the service.

Comment: instead of using Start/Stop schema, use Bind/Unbind to that Service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**QUESTION**
*I want to create this service to work with multiple activities. I mean each activity will be able to send a data to this service and get a data from it.*

You don't have to do nothing with your `Service`. Services remain the same if they are not destroyed, that means **all your `Activities` will be able to access to it's data**.

**PROBLEM**

> *but the method onStartCommand inside the service, doesn't get called..*

**WHY**
As long as your service has started, the [`onStartCommand`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int)) is not called each time:

[`onStartCommand`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int))

> Called by the system every time a client explicitly starts the service by calling **startService**(Intent), providing the arguments it supplied and a unique integer token representing the start request.

[`startService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService(android.content.Intent))

> Request that a given application service be started.

**SOLUTION**
call the events you need in [`onRebind`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onRebind(android.content.Intent)) method:

> Called when new clients have connected to the service, after it had previously been notified that all had disconnected in its onUnbind(Intent). This will only be called if the implementation of onUnbind(Intent) was overridden to return true.

Comment: hi thanks, but if you'll notice.. i do call to startService with intent.. as i understand, once startService is getting called, the onStartCommand should be also get called. no?

Comment: if you take a look to links in the answer you will nottice `startService` is a `Context` method, so `onStartCommand` is not being called... It's important to understand lifecycle in Android apps to know what and why is happening

Comment: ok but if I call this method by using this: "getApplicationContext().start..."
it doesn't work also

Comment: Service does not have this method, you're already calling it by `startService(service);`, please read the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int)

Comment: ok I understand. I'll explain again what i'm trying to do: lets say I have 2 activities,activity A starts the service and now I'm moving to activity B.
In activity B I have a button, when this button is clicked by the user, I want to send a data to the service. I did it by calling again to startService with an intent as a parameter. the doc says that when you call to startService the method 'onStartCommand' get called also

Comment: true... problem is: the `startService` method **is not really being called because the service is already started** for this you need to stop service and restart it again. **NOTE:** if service behaviour was not this one, you need to create a singletton service to share between appplications

Comment: The second activity must call bindService() not startService(). Then define the communication between second activity and service in onBind().

Answer (score 5):

Hi you need to bind your running service to activity you need to access it again. Following code snippets you can used as a reference

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    bindService(mIntent, mConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
};

ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mBounded = false;
        myService= null;
    }

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        // Toast.makeText(context, "Service is connected", 1000).show();

        mBounded = true;
        LocalBinder mLocalBinder = (LocalBinder) service;
        myService= mLocalBinder.getServerInstance();

      //now you are able to access any method in service class 
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

this what i did to make different activities to send and receive data from service

```
 public class SensorsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
BluetoothService mService;
boolean mBound = false;

String valueReceived;
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.v("STATE", "onStart() is called");
    // Bind to BluetoothService
    if (!mBound) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, BluetoothService.class);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sensors);

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(SensorsActivity.this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
            new IntentFilter("in.purelogic.simsonite.REQUEST_PROCESSED"));
}

private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                   IBinder service) {
        // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
        BluetoothService.LocalBinder binder = (BluetoothService.LocalBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mBound = false;
    }
};

//BroadCastReceiver to let the MainActivity know that there's message has been recevied
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            handleMessage(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

//The Message that comes from the service
private void handleMessage(Intent msg) throws Exception {
    Bundle data = msg.getExtras();
    valueReceived = data.getString("DATA");
    Log.e("recv2", valueReceived);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Hey call your service with below intent

```
 Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);

service.putExtra("dataToSend",data.toString());

 startService(mIntent);
```

in your case you are passing service class name and that will become action to your intent. So service won't start.

onstartCommand will call every time when you call startService and you can get data from intent which passed as extra.

To receive data from service to your activity. you can broadcast data from service and register broadcast in your activities

or

you can use binding mechanism

Answer (score -1):

one possible solution but not the best is using sharedpreferences .
you can use it as a massage Transmitter from your activity to your service.